# How to use ITrackCancel to escape IRubberBand track?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, arcgis-engine, .net, wpf

I have a `BaseTool` for AX_MapControl and AX_PageLayoutControl that allows to draw a polyline via `IRubberBand`. But once the rubberband is started, you can't cancel it e.g. by hitting escape. I found `ITrackCancel` but unfortunatly no way to use it properly.

```
ITrackCancel2 esc = new CancelTrackerClass();
esc.CancelOnKeyPress = true;
esc.Reset();

IRubberBand2 rubberBand = new RubberLineClass();
IGeometry geometry = rubberBand.TrackNew(screenDisplay, null);
IPolyline polyline = (IPolyline)geometry;
```

How do I use ITrackCancel to cancel the rubberband tracking?

**Update:** 
ITrackCancel can be retrieved from `IScreenDisplay` but my `m_hookHelper.ActiveView.ScreenDisplay.CancelTracker` is null. I use the tool with `AX_MapControl` and `AX_PageLayoutControl`.

**Update 2:** 
I found out, that even Esris own tools like `esriControls.ControlsNewLineTool` can't be canceled with escape in my application. Maybe there is a deeper flaw somewhere. Going to dive deeper into it...

**Update 3 (Solution):**
There is a glitch in my WPF application. It seems, that on startup no key events arrive the MapControl until you change the window size once. So this is not a problem with `ITrackCancel` but with the interaction between WPF and ArcEngine.
Thanks anyways for your help.

Comment: Did you try setting  `m_hookHelper.ActiveView.ScreenDisplay.CancelTracker = esc;` ?

Comment: Yes Kirk, but it didn't work either.

Comment: Reaction to update 3: I guess now you should either mark one of answers as correct or post your own answer (and mark it as correct).

Comment: Thanks Petr, I wasn't quite sure, because it isn't a real answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both suggested answers do work fine. I had another failure in my WPF application, that caused this behavior. 
It seems, that after the start no key event arrived the MapControl until one changes the window size once. After that all worked as exspected. So it was not a problem with `ITrackCancel` but with the interaction between WPF and ArcEngine.

Comment: How did you work around the WPF problem?

Comment: Unfortunatly I haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for [rubber bands](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#Rubber%20bands) suggests that they *should* support cancelling via pressing the Esc key.

If that really does not work for you, consider using a [display feedback](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#Display%20feedbacks) instead, e.g. the [NewLineFeedback](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/NewLineFeedbackClass_Class/001w000003qw000000/). Display feedbacks are a bit more involved than rubber bands, but they are not necessarily that much difficult to use. Plus, you can [Stop](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Stop_Method/001w0000023n000000/) most feedbacks at will at any time (e.g. upon pressing Esc).

Comment: Thanks, Petr. I will try the display feedback. Btw. your display feedback link seems wrong. I guess you meant to link to [IDisplayFeedback](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/001w/001w000000r1000000.htm).

Comment: Using `NewLineFeedback` definitly works. I hook up the tools `OnKeyDown` event to escape on Escape. Anyways, the problem wasn't with `ITrackCancel` at all, see my question update 3.

Answer (score 1):

ScreenDisplay coclass is implementing IScreendisplay which has a CancelTracker member [IScreenDisplay Interface](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IScreenDisplay_Interface/001w000002s1000000/)
..So it should get the escape button press as far as i know..the below code works..

```
public override void OnMouseDown(int Button, int Shift, int X, int Y)
        {

            IMxDocument pMxDoc = (IMxDocument)m_application.Document ;
            IGraphicsContainer pGraCont = (IGraphicsContainer)pMxDoc.ActiveView;
            IRubberBand pRubberLine = new RubberLineClass();
            IElement pElement;
            IPolyline pPolyline = (IPolyline)pRubberLine.TrackNew(pMxDoc.ActiveView.ScreenDisplay,null);
            pElement = new LineElementClass();
            pElement.Geometry = pPolyline;
            pGraCont.AddElement(pElement,0);
            pMxDoc.ActiveView.Refresh();

        }
```

Comment: My Tool is for AX_MapControl and AX_PageLayoutControl so I tried your code with my `IHookHelper` instead of your `IMxDocument` but it didn't work. `m_hookHelper.ActiveView.ScreenDisplay.CancelTracker` is null. So it seems to be different somehow.